# Cribbage run question

Tags: cribbage

Player one plays a one.  Player two plays a three .  player one plays a two.  Player two plays a three and says she has a run.  I disagree because the last three cards are 3 2 3.  What is correct?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Cribbage rules on pagat.com](https://www.pagat.com/adders/crib6.html), you are correct.

Player one makes a run when playing the 2 after 1, 3, but player two doesn't make a run after playing the second 3 because 3, 2, 3 isn't a run.

Relevant rules passage quoted from pagat.com

> A run or sequence is a set of 3 or more cards of consecutive ranks (irrespective of suit) - such as 9-10-jack or 2-3-4-5.

> Another example: 4-2-3-4-3. The player of the first 3 scores 3 for the run 4-2-3. Then the player of the second 4 score 3 for the run 2-3-4. The player of the second 3 scores nothing because the 3 does not complete a run.